# What are constant arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

What are constant arrays?

If we define

```
const char hex_char[] = {
                           '0', '1', '2', '3', 
                           '4', '5', '6', '7', 
                           '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 
                           'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'
                        };
```

Then, it should not be modified by program; What does it mean?

Comment: Since `const` protect its left side unless there's nothing to it's left, then it protects its right side. On the right is the array, in this case, you can't change the elements in the array.

Comment: What do u mean by protect?

Comment: Protect it from evil changes (Doesn't allow the value it protects to change). Changes by mistake or that wasn't suppose to happen.

Comment: How it protect its left side?

Comment: For example, if you write `int* const ptr = vec;` then you **cannot** change the location `ptr` points to, e.g. `ptr = NULL` (the `*` is on the left side).

Comment: @haccks this is called [const correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness), you should go through this wiki tutorial.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means that you can't modify its content. For example you are not allowed to do `hex_char[i] = 'A'`, it will result in compilation time error.

Comment: +1. And a compilation time error is a way better than a runtime error. That's one of the advantages of the `const` keyword.

Comment: @Grijesh If i want to change the 10th element 'A' by 'a' somewhere in the program, then it will show compilation error, right?

Comment: @haccks yes, it will that what I used `i`, even if you don't change value (any assignment is error) e.g `hex_char[0] = '0';` is an error.

Comment: @haccks Thanks! consider djf's answer and Brett Hale's comment to his answer. very nice points. (and feel free if you wants to change your acceptance of answer). Good Luck!

Comment: @haccks If you found this answer helpful (It is..), accept it :)

Comment: Let me go through the other answers :)

Comment: @haccks someone down-voted me serially :( ..[he is some Shoat](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/__kLZHfshpZA/SoG3rKMtRsI/AAAAAAAABcA/Ip-Oewr78Rs/s200/Ninja_Pig.jpg)

Comment: @MarounMaroun can you review my recently added answer for java.

Answer (score 5):

Attempting to modify a const qualified object yields undefined behavior. Some C compilers even store them in read-only segments of memory.

As [Grijesh Chauhan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17167622/961781) has pointed out, modifying the array directly should give you a compiler error. But using `memcpy`, `strcpy` or similar functions might only give you warnings. However, these aren't legal to use either. So don't do it!

Comment: +1 for mentioning read-only segments / pages. Can't cheat by casting away const, so it's often more than just a semantic qualifier.

Comment: @djf; What do umean by 'using `memcpy`, `strcpy` or similar functions might only give you warnings'?I did't understand :(

Comment: @haccks - Let's say you *knew* an array `vec` was *not* declared as a constant, but was passed to your function as a `const char *vec` - it's (very) bad practice, but you could 'cast away' the `const` with `(char) vec`, and modify its contents: `((char) vec)[0] = 1;`

Comment: @BrettHale but `((char*)hex_char)[0] = 'A';` is valid, `(char) vec` wil be error that `vec` is pointer and you are casting to `char`

Comment: @haccks For instance: [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) will copy a given amount of bytes from the source pointer to the destination pointer. The destination has to be modifiable. If you accidentally specify your `hex_char` as destination, memcpy will attempt to modify a const array, nontheless. My point was that in this case, the compiler will only emit a warning message, but it will still build the program. This is much more sneaky, because then you end up with undefined behavior at runtime. I guess what I'm trying to say is, compiler warnings shouldn't be ignored.

Comment: @haccks - Now if `vec` was declared `const`, the program may put its contents in a *read-only* data section, enforced by the OS / CPU itself. Trying to modify it through a `(char *)` cast will typically result in a 'segmentation fault', 'access violation' or a similar condition, and abort the program. Technically, the C standard regards this stuff as *UB* : *undefined behavior* - but this is what happens in practice. NOTE: As Grijesh pointed out, I should have used `(char *)` in the previous comment, not `(char)`.

Comment: @djf; " the compiler will only emit a warning message";
Does it means that `hex_char` will modify somehow?

Comment: OK i got it man! And thanks for your answer(+1) & attentive replies.