# meaning of static array of characters?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, static

#### somewhere I read the following lines :-

```
char *p  = "string literal";
```

My program crashes if I try to assign a new value to `p[i]`.

> A:-It turns into an unnamed, `static array of characters`, and this unnamed array may be stored in read-only memory, and which therefore cannot necessarily be modified. In an expression context, the array is converted at once to a pointer, as usual (see section 6), so the declaration initializes p to point to the unnamed array's first element.

I know what `static` do but I did not understand the following in the above lines

`static array of characters`.

Comment: Link to OP: "somewhere" http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html

Comment: Kelvin read first two points here [static](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/static)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : maybe I was also confused as I thought that the author was referring to `static` in terms of `c` but he was referring to `static` in terms of English.

Comment: @kevingomes yes author referring English meaning of static in that particular line.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : I am also confused with literal. Please tell me what a literal means and how does it is different from char array

Comment: @kevingomes ["a **literal** is a notation for representing a fixed value in source code."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_programming%29)

Comment: @kevingomes I just means it is hard-coded value. remember in c99 you have const keyword so a array can be defined [constant array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167601/what-are-constant-arrays/17167622#17167622) still literal word exists there. Yes of-course you can't modify literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not refer  to the static keyword, but static in the sense that it cannot be changed.

EDIT: Thinking better, it seems this phrase was badly written, I think the author back then (for those wondering, this comes from the [C faq](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html)) meant "constant"

EDIT2: OP asked what is a `string literal`, here is the answer:

String literal is a string that is hardcoded in your source (and later in your compiled program), you do it by using double quotes `"` a example would be this `"some string literal here"`

When you assigned this to a pointer, the pointer points to the string literal, that is stored in your program running code, NOT on the main memory, this is why it cannot be modified.

You can assign a string literal to array, to initialize the array, the meaning there is different, where the array will be sent to the memory, and will have that string as its initial value.

Mind you, a `string literal` must be inside double quotes `"` if you attempt other hacks it won't compile at all. You cannot for example do this: `char* someVar = {'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'};` it won't work at all. (my compiler gives the error: `excess elements in scalar initializer`)

Comment: ya, must be some mistake with the phrase. As far as I know `static` means that the value of a variable will be alive between different function calls.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The phrasing is correct in english, but confusing if you guess that words on it are keywords (they aren't). The author of this very historical text should have been more careful when writing it.

Comment: I am also confused with literal. Please tell me what a literal means and how does it is different from char array.

Comment: Literal in C means that is a string between "" ( "this is a literal" ), compared to a non-literal string {'t', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'n', 'o', 't', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'l', 'i', 't', 'e', 'r', 'a', 'l', '\0'}

Comment: you mean to say that `"hello"` is a string literal whereas `{'h','e','l','l','o','\0'}` is not

Comment: A literal is just a literal (it is a string inside quotes), the meaning of the literal is what the faq you mentioned explains, you can use it to initialize a array (that can be modified), or as a constant string (that you cannot modify), some compilers allow you to set a flag that explicitly compiles any literal as const char* to make this more explicit and easier to catch compile time errors

Comment: Yes, exactly kevin :)

Answer (score 1):

"Static" refers to the [storage duration](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1256.html#6.2.4) of the object that will be created for the string literal.

To quote [C99 6.4.5](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1256.html#6.4.5p5):

> The multibyte character sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage    duration and length just  sufficient to contain the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Simply string literals refer to *string constants*  about which C11 standard says that:

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>   appropriate values. **If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined**.

It can't change during program execution. While the string variables  can change during program execution. String variables are arrays of characters whose last element is a `NUL` character (`\0`).
All string (variables) are array of characters but all character arrays are not string.

When compiler encounters a string literal, then it stores it in the read only section of memory, i.e, ROM. Here the word `static` refers to `unmodifiable` not the keyword `static`.

A string literal:

```
char *string_literal = "string literal";
```

or this can also be seen as

```
char *string_literal = {'s','t','r','i','n','g',' ','l','i','t','e','r','a','l','\0'};
```

A string variable

```
char string_var[] = "string variable";
```

or it can also be seen as

```
char string_var[] = {'s','t','r','i','n','g',' ','v','a','r','i','a','b','l','e', '\0'};
```

A character array:

```
char character_array[] = {'c','h','a','r','a','c','t','e','r',' ', 'a', 'r', 'r', 'a', 'y'};
```

Comment: It's pretty obvious that "static" refers to the storage duration. In your (an others') interpretation, the sentence could be rephrased to: "It turns into an unnamed, unmodifiable array of characters, and this unnamed array may be stored in read-only memory, and which therefore cannot necessarily be modified." or shorter "you can not modify it and you can maybe not modify it!".

Comment: I didn't downvoted but I think that along `char arrays` , `string literals` are also terminated with `\0`.

Comment: @kevingomes; Yes string literals are also terminated with `\0` but it is not necessary that all character arrays terminated with `\0`.

Comment: @rmartinjak; Well, here `static` is not the keyword for sure.

Comment: @haccks : please give a example

Comment: @haccks I am perfectly aware of that.